# How do I apply autostash after an aborted rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-stash

I have `rebase.autoStash` set to `'true'` in my `.gitconfig`, which allows me to run `rebase` on a dirty worktree. However, if a `rebase` is aborted for some reason, all changes to tracked files are gone (i.e. the autostash is not reapplied). What's the proper way to apply the autostash in such cases?

How to reproduce:

- Run `git config rebase.autostash true`.
- Edit some tracked files.
- Run `git rebase -i HEAD^^^`. This prints something like:

  ```
  Created autostash: 75a5188
  HEAD is now at f0c93f1 WIP
  ```
- Abort the rebase, e.g. have the editor exit with an error code (`:cq` in Vim).

Comment: Can't reproduce. Doing the specified sequence gives me re-applied stash. Also git explicitly logs stash SHA-1, so you may restore the state by ID. git-2.6.5

Comment: Look at http://pastebin.com/wETbyMik As you may see, git restored the stash after failed rebase. If it doesn't you always can do something like `git checkout 75a5188 -- .` and continue your work

Comment: @user3159253: can you try exiting the editor with an error code (e.g. `:cq` in Vim)? That's probably what I used to abort the rebase.

Comment: Ahha. This way I've reproduced your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply the autostash using `git stash apply` and the SHA-1 hash that was printed by `git rebase`:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD^^^
Created autostash: 3ac3f4a
HEAD is now at f0c93f1 WIP
# abort the rebase...    
$ git stash apply 3ac3f4a
On branch master
...
```

Comment: If for some reason you can't see the autostash hash (the rebase was done in a script or you don't have enough history in your terminal), the hash of the autostash is in the file `.git/rebase-apply/autostash`

Answer (score 2):

Even if git has failed to restore the state, you can always do it manually using `git checkout <stash-id> -- .` where `<stash-id>` is reported in `Created autostash: ...` line

Comment: This is not exactly eqivalent to 'applying the autostash', see my answer for an alternative.

Comment: I would use `git stash pop` but nevertheless, it works

Comment: Nope, `git stash pop` gives `No stash found.` Apparently, `rebase` doesn't store the stash anywhere.

Comment: oops, then probably your solution is the best one.