# git pull --rebase --autostash losing files on conflict

Tags: git

I tried:

```
>git pull --rebase --autostash
```

which resulted in:

```
Created autostash: 019054d
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        FILENAME
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
fatal: Could not detach HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

I then handled the issue with FILENAME, and at this point I want to either revert to the state *before* trying the pull or continuing but:

```
C:\Projekte\FLOS>git pull --rebase --autostash
fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
        git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
        rm -fr ".git/rebase-apply"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.
```

```
>git rebase --abort
error: could not read '.git/rebase-apply/head-name': No such file or directory
```

(indeed the file does not exist, but a `autostash` file exists in that folder)

but the `git stash list` command does not show the stash created.

How do I recover all the changes which where supposed to be stashed?

Comment: This is most probably a bug in Git, you could report it to the [Git mailing list](https://git-scm.com/community) with a reproducer. Are you using the latest version of Git ?

Comment: This is one of multiple reasons I dislike rebase's autostash. Historically there have been various bugs with it, just as there have been bugs with `git stash`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've got it solved. But this can't be the intended workflow.

As suggested in:
[How do I apply autostash after an aborted rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252108/how-do-i-apply-autostash-after-an-aborted-rebase)

i `git stash apply 019054d` (with the hash of the autostash) -> it worked even though I could not see the stash with `git stash list`

then I `rm -fr ".git/rebase-apply"` to get out of the rebase process.

Comment: Don't forcibly remove the rebase-apply directory: use `git rebase --abort` or `git rebase --quit`, depending on which of those you want. Then use `git stash apply`. (If you want `--quit` and have an ancient Git that lacks it, *then* resort to the rather harsh `rm -rf` method. But generally you should ask Git to stop, because that's not always where the files are. If you're working in an added work-tree, that's the wrong thing to remove!)

Comment: I know Git said to do that. This is just a general caveat. You've hit a bug of sorts here, and you shouldn't have to do any of this. If/when the bug is fixed, `git rebase --abort` or `git rebase --quit` should re-apply the stash for you. (Also, consider applying with `--index`.)